# php script to execute multiple urls? My script not working

Tags: php, curl, cron

I want to build a script to execute multiple urls (say 100) at a time.
The script I am using the code as

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url1");




curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url2");




curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url15");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);




// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But the script is executing only last two urls, not all. What should a correct script to execute multiple urls?

Comment: Can you paste your code here instead of adding a pastebin link please.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

CURLOPT_URL just sets a string, setting it twice overwrites the previous value.
you're probably looking for curl_multi, it can execute multiple urls at the same time, and is a pain to use, check the examples of http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "url1");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "url2");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```